# Save table data as a XML file

Tags: asp.net, xml, linq, ado.net, asp.net-3.5

Below is my SQL syntax:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Security_Module_Info](
    [Client_Company_ID] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [Module_ID] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [Module_Name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Module_Description] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
    [Is_Active] [bit] NULL,
    [Active_Date] [smalldatetime] NULL,
    [Record_Status] [tinyNULL,
    [Maker_ID] [smallint] NULL,
    [Make_Date] [smalldatetime] NULL,
    [Checker_ID] [smallint] NULL,
    [Check_Date] [smalldatetime] NULL,
    [Authorizer_ID] [smallint] NULL,
    [Authorize_Date] [smalldatetime] NULL,
    [Record_Action_Type] [tinyint] NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Security_Module_Info] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Client_Company_ID] ASC,
    [Module_ID] ASC
) WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

I want to create a **XML** file on my project's App_Data folder. This XML use as the source file of my AspxMenu. I know how to bind **XML** data to AspxMenu but I don't know how to create **XML** file .I want to save this table information as a XML file on my App_Data folder. Help me to save table information as a XML file.

Any suggestion, advice and reply is welcome.

Comment: You can directly bind AspxMenu to the SQL table right?

Comment: purpose of menu ,i don't want to connect with database.I like to use server resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use LINQ to XML (http://www.hookedonlinq.com/LINQtoXML5MinuteOverview.ashx) as a means to copy the data over too.  You don't have to convert to data table.  LINQ to XML would be done by looping through your resultset and writing the object's data to the XML.  Also, you could try an XML serializer (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx) to convert the object, but if that object has any entity set relationships this may throw an error (XML Serialization can only serialize to so many levels I think).

HTH.

Answer (score 2):

are you looking for something like..

```
System.Data.DataTable dtbl = new System.Data.DataTable();
//dtbl fill your datatable from DB here
dtbl.WriteXml("String FileName Where you want to store");
```

Comment: you just show the path .There's no syntax to store data from database as xml

Comment: NorthwindDataContext db = new NorthwindDataContext();
            var r = from p in db.Categories
                    select p;
I can not write .r.WriteXml("String FileName Where you want to store");How to write it?

Comment: convert it into data table and data table have this method support

Comment: This Method using with ADO.NET,This is no framework(linq or entity)